# is it possible to do 2 opposite bit operations in one statement?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am kind of new on c++ and a complete newb when it comes to bit operations (i know only the basics) and i am working on a project where i am in the need to keep the status of a document in a bitfield.

In short: i want to preserve the last state of flag1 while removing flag2 unconditionally.
What i have at the moment is something like this:

```
bitfield |= flag1; bitfield &= ~flag2;
```

The question is: *is there a way to perform that in one statement?*

In my case i cant really toggle them like this:

```
bitfield ^= (flag1|flag2)
```

It was the obvious answer that came to mind but the problem is that flag1 some times is set and some times it isnt and I want to preserve it as i received it from the last function call while removing flag2.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can if you invert your definition of either flag1 or flag2. Then you do both with a single or or and.

Comment: After the first statement, flag1 will always be set, so I'm puzzled when you say it's only set sometimes. If the goal of the *pair* of instructions is only to remove flag2 while preserving the state of flag1, then simply omit the first statement; the `&` statement *already* preserves flag1. This is assuming that flag1 and flag2 do not overlap.

Comment: Your text does not match your code, or as Rob is saying you're omitting some assumptions. "preserve the last state of flag1 while removing flag2 unconditionally" would mean that flag2 has no bits to clear that flag1 has to set, or your code quite visibly would clear them anyway. Clear your flag2 bits *first*, then set your flag1 bits again; this preserves them.

Comment: Whether you do it in one statement or two they probably both result in _identical_ assembly output. Keep it simple and clear and let the optimizer make it fast.

Comment: ok, sorry for the misunderstanding but yes, flag1 is set/removed in other parts of my code. The variable containing the flags is static so i receive the bitfield with some bits set/removed already. I `OR` flag1 as to preserve it, and then procede to remove flag2. Which I never said it was wrong I just wanted to know if it was possible to do it in one statement. The first part of the answer below is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could obviously do

```
 bitfield = (bitfield | flag1) & ~flag2;
```

and you could use the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), e.g.

```
 (bitfield |= flag1), (bitfield &= ~flag2);
```

Comment: you say "_obviously_" but the idea never came that the order of the grouping would affect the outcome... I even tried something like `bitfield |= (flag1|flag2) & ~flag2` at some point but never thought of using the bitfield itself >_>

Comment: It is obvious, because it is just rewriting your statements, and is not specific to bitfields. You can replace `|` by `+` and `&` by `*` and the rewriting still works.